# Why is my dropdown not working?

Tags: drop-down-menu

I can't get this to work! 
I've tried messing with the boostrap source, gone through other problems with dropdowns on stackoverflow and threw it jsfiddle a bit earlier and didn't work there either.

Help much appreciated! Cheers

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle btn-md" type="button" id="dropDown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown</button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header">DropHeader</li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>

    <li role="seperator" class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header">DropOtherHeader</li>

    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have the bootstrap.js referenced as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include JS scripts.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You have not included JS files.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle btn-md" type="button" id="dropDown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Dropdown</button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header">DropHeader</li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>

    <li role="seperator" class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header">DropOtherHeader</li>

    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```